# Can I use before_save to sort nested_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code in my Release model to save tracks associated with a release. In it's current state, the tracks are saved to the DB in a random order. I'm aware the SQL statements are not executed in a set order and the cause.

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true

 def track_attributes=(track_attributes)
   track_attributes.each do |attributes|
     tracks.build(attributes)
     artists_tracks.build(attributes)
   end
 end
```

Is it possible to add a order_tracks def with a before_save call to ensure they go into the DB in the correct order? I have track_number field that can be used to determine the order.

Something like this?

```
before_save :order tracks

def order_tracks
tracks.sort_by { |track| track.track_number }
end
```

(The above doesn't work)

EDIT

I've found a related issue. I was previously setting label and user ids via the track controller create action using:

```
@track.user_id = current_user.id
@track.label_id = @release.label.id
```

Now i'm adding tracks via accepts_nested_attributes this no longer works.

I'm thinking if I can figure out where to set these, I can write something similar to set the position in my releases_tracks model manually rather than via acts_as_list.

Comment: Should be before_save :order_tracks, but that's probably a typo not your problem.

Comment: Yep, typo on here....it's correct in my model but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to select those tracks in specific order. Then you can define `:order` param in your association, for example:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks, :order => "track_number asc"
end
```

Comment: I already have this, it works fine in terms of displaying the tracks in my view....but it's important they get added to the db in the correct order as there's a join table with acts_as_list creating a position that I want to use eventually to allow drag and drop re-ordering....

Comment: ah but how are you ensuring that the tracks are added in the right order to begin with? I'd have the form contain a track number field for each track.

Comment: That's the problem - they're not being added in the right order. I can fake the order with my track number field, but for example if I have primary_key/name/track_number i might get 1/Three/3 & 2/One/1 & 3/Two/2 . The primary key itself is irrelevant, but the order records are added is, as it seems acts_as_list numbers the position field in the join based on this.